# Disabling browser back button works but first it browses back and then browses forward

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to disallow the user from browsing back to the previous page in the browser.

To achieve that, I put that piece of code below in the layout pages of my ASP.NET MVC app (in addition to sending appropriate response headers from the server):

```
function noBack() {
    window.history.forward();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("pageshow", "body", function (event) {
        if (event.persisted)
            noBack(); 
        });
});


...

<body onload = "noBack();">
```

There are two problems I am looking for the solution to:

1) Currently, this code behaves strangely but consistently on all browsers. What it does is, when I press the Back button on any browser, including IE, it browses back to the previous page for a moment, it loads it and displays it nicely, and then browses forward again to return to the page we were viewing when we pressed the Back button.

This is irritating. How do I get rid of this?

2) The `pageshow` event, as I understand is not supported by IE. Please tell me if there's an alternative for IE? I need to support IE 8 and upwards in addition to FireFox and Chrome.

*Side note: I know it's not a good practice to mess with the client's/user's browser and it's better to just disable output caching by having the server send the appropriate response headers, but my client insists that I also disable/disallow the browser's back and forward button function.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript file, just put this at the top of the file (or on your _layout page):

```
window.history.forward();
```

Every time the script is loaded, it will go forward. If it can't go forward, it does nothing. This essentially disables the back functionality.

Comment: Thank you. What an answer. Simple, unpretentious and correct. :-)